# Calculating height of NSString with custom font

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to solve this problem for a week now and I have tested a lot of ideas that I had on my mind but I'm unable to properly calculate size of the `NSString` with custom font.

I have `UITextView` which contains text and one `UIView` on which I draw line numbers for the lines in `UITextView`. The problem is that `NSString` `UIKit` Additions are ignoring tab width in calculation of size of the `NSString`.

Here on picture you can see that clearly on line 7, which is line with line break when rendered in `UITextView`, and after that all lines are affected.

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Font that I'm using is [Adobe Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe/source-code-pro).

I have tried all methods from `NSString` `UIKit` Additions without success.

```
sizeWithFont

sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:

sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
```

I have also tried to replace all tabs in string with four spaces, it helps, but still it doesn't work all the time. For some lines it helps but for some it doesn't.

Any suggestions how to calculate `NSString` height properly? `CoreText` maybe?

One small note. I have tried to solve this also with using Geometry hit testing methods from `UITextInput` Protocol and while they are working, cpu load is 100% on simulator, so on real device it's going to kill the app, specially if I load file that is about 1500+ lines of code.

And here is the gist with code that I'm using for [LineNumbersView.m](https://gist.github.com/22259bce9ceea480335e).

Comment: Just want to know, do it work with system fonts?

Comment: That's something that I thought about a while ago, will test it. It could be font problem. Tnx. I will let you know as soon as I have tested it.

Comment: I have tested it right now. Out of the box it's working a bit better than with custom font but only if I replace all tabs with 4 spaces, but it's still broken on some lines. I'm using `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]`.

Comment: Have you tried - (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size ?

Comment: Yes I have. Actually right now I'm using `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if it's a fixed-size font why do you need some fancy to calculate size?

Comment: (What is "enter code here"?)

Comment: What do you mean with "enter code here?" Regarding calculation I need to calculate where are the line breaks and to draw line number on the beginning of the line. This is the simplest solution that I could find for this particular problem. If you have suggestion how to do this I'm all in ears.

Comment: I mean you've got the text "enter code here" in your question, and it doesn't make any sense in that context.

Comment: Oh, I didn't saw that at all. It must be some kind of formatting error. I will fix that now.

Comment: Yes it is, it's regular UITextView, so line numbers are being redrawn on textChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `UITextView` and Core Text always exactly agree then the latter is definitely a solution, though it's not desperately straightforward for this problem.

You'd:

1. create an attributed string of the text in the main view, having set the appropriate font across the entire range;
2. create a suitable framesetter for the attributed string (using [`CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString));
3. create a `CGPath` that describes the drawing area that the string will be drawn to (either as a `UIBezierPath` and then getting the [CGPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBezierPath/CGPath) property or by creating one and using [`CGPathAddRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathAddRect));
4. hence create a frame from the framesetter plus the path plus the subrange of the string you're interested in, which will likely be all of it (see [`CTFramesetterCreateFrame`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFramesetterCreateFrame));
5. from the frame you can then obtain a `CFArray` of the individual lines it would output (using [`CTFrameGetLines`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFrameRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFrameGetLines)), though these are the on-screen typeset lines rather than your source lines;
6. for each line you can get the range of the original string that it contains (using [`CTLineGetStringRange`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTLineRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTLineGetStringRange)), allowing you to determine which begin immediately after your original newline characters rather than due to word wrap;
7. you can also get a C array of `CGPoint`s where each represents the origin of an on-screen line ([`CTFrameGetLineOrigins`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFrameRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFrameGetLineOrigins)); by using what you learn in (6) to look up positions in that you can get the on-screen origins of the relevant lines.

For added fun, the pixel output of Core Text is identical on OS X and on iOS. However OS X considers the screen's original to be the lower left corner, like graph paper. iOS considers it to the top left corner, like English reading order. The roughly worded net effect is that on iOS Core Text draws upside down. So you'll need to take that into account. In iOS terms you'll apparently see the first line as being at the very bottom of your frame, the second as being one line above that, etc. You'll need to flip those coordinates.

It'll probably end up being just a hundred or so lines of code even though you're jumping through so many hoops.

Comment: I have had already implemented similar solution but I had problems with it as well. Although difference was in nr. 6 where I have used `CTFrameGetLineOrigins` to get origins of all lines without calling `CTLineGetStringRange` before and then scanning each line for `[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]`. It seems that `CoreText` will be solution in the end, although I need to get it first to display text in the same way as `UITextView`.

Comment: @AmarKulo my query above about whether the `UITextView` needs to be editable was implicitly about how easily you could replace the text view with a manually implemented Core Text alternative, giving you 100% control...

Comment: I have tried to create UIView with CoreText and I still have problems with CoreText representation of tabs as well as line breaks. For example `UITextView` will display string " * @license  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
" as 3 lines where it will leave @link in the first one and url in the second one and "license.html" in third one, while `CoreText` display this text as 2 lines and it breaks line on " * @license  http://", showing the rest in the another line.